# How to remove black stripes from image?

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, sentinel-1

I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of these black lines in my images by creating a mask using the VV pixels. How can I get rid of these lines?

[image: shows black stripes across a map]

```
// Load Sentinel-1 C-band SAR Ground Range collection (log scale, VV, ascending)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'))
.filterMetadata('resolution_meters', 'equals' , 10)
.filterBounds(roi)
.select('VV');

//Filter by date
var april_May2015 = collection.filterDate('2015-04-01', '2015-05-30').mosaic();

//print(before, 'Sentinel-1 Collection');
// Display map
//Map.centerObject(roi, 7);
//Map.addLayer(before, {min:-15, max:0}, 'Before flood', 0);

//Apply filter to reduce speckle
var SMOOTHING_RADIUS = 50;
var april_May2015_filtered = april_May2015.focal_mean(SMOOTHING_RADIUS, 'circle', 
'meters');

// remove stripes
//function stripeMaskVV(april_May2015_filtered) {
// VH backscatter of stripes is often less than -30dB
//  var mask = ee.Image(0).where(april_May2015_filtered.select('VV').lte(-40), 1).not();
//  return april_May2015_filtered.updateMask(mask);
//}

function stripeMaskVV(april_May2015_filtered) {
  var img = april_May2015_filtered.gt(-40); // make a mask image
  april_May2015_filtered = april_May2015_filtered.updateMask(img);
  return(april_May2015_filtered);
}

//Clip the images to our area of interest
var april_May2015_filtered_clip = april_May2015_filtered.clip(roi);

//Display filtered images
Map.addLayer(april_May2015_filtered_clip, {min:-15,max:0}, 'April May 2015',0);

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
image: april_May2015_filtered_clip,
description: 'april_May2015',
scale: 10,
region: roi,
fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
});
```

Comment: This looks like you might have a gap between neighboring images, so getting rid of the black still might not give you data there. Or when you are smoothing are pixels within 50m of the edge getting removed? i.e. does the smoothing ignore NoData values?

Comment: @ycartwhelen I'm very new to this, is there any way to fill the gaps? Thank you

Comment: It depends - I'm not sure if you have data that's being covered up or removed at some point in the processing, or if there never was any data in those stripes to begin with.

Comment: @ycartwhelen Okay, I appreciate the help! Thank you